# Django rest framework No module named .serializers

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

For some reason my serialize module is not being recognized, any ideas why this is? I have installed rest_framework and have it in my settings.py file under apps.

For some reason though my serializer.py file is showing rest_framework import is 'unresolved', not sure why this is or if that is the cause of the problem but I have had that before where my editor seems to sometimes mark imports as unresolved but still work.

Here is my serializes.py

```
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets, permissions
from .models import Part, Supplier, SupplierPart


class PartSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Part
        field = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'code',
        ]


class SupplierSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        field = [
            'id',
            'name',
        ]


class SupplierPartSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    part = PartSerializer()
    supplier = SupplierSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = SupplierPart
        field = [
            'id',
            'part',
            'supplier',
            'supplier_code',
            'description',
            'price',
            'sale_price',
            'quantity',
            'photo',
            'url',
        ]


class SupplierPartViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SupplierPart.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SupplierPartSerializer
```

Here is my URls:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers

from SupplierPart.serializers import SupplierPartViewSet


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"SupplierPart", SupplierPartViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
    url(r'^$', include('haystack.urls')),
    url(r'^part/', include('products.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))

]
```

I am getting this error though when I try to go to my site 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your code, `SupplierPart` is a model. And you are trying to import serializers from it in your urls.py file.
When, you should import it from the app. For example. if your serializers.py is located in `suppliers` app (folder/package) then you should import it like this:
`from suppliers.serializers import SomeSerializer`

P.S.
serializers.py file is supposed to hold Serializers, not ViewSets

Answer (score 0):

---->>>>>>>>>>>> 
`use "from rest_framework.serializers import *"`

---

i resolved this error by replace 
"from rest_framework import serializers"
with 
"from rest_framework.serializers import *"

Answer (score 0):

If your serializers are in different folder nested somewhere in your app in django and you get this error even though the import seems to be okay,

try to create inside the nested folder empty file and call it `__init__.py`.

For example:

if I have chat app inside django project and want to seperate my serializers into different folder which I will call serializers it will look like this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem try  using the . before serializer when trying to use the serializers. e.g.,

from .serializers import UserSerializer

Answer (score -1):

about the unresolved imports: are you using a virtualenv? if so, be sure your IDE is using it as interpreter.

Comment: Hell yes I am using virtual environment, how do I check that my IDE is using it as an interpreter?

Comment: First of all, which IDE are you using? If you're using PyCharm for instance, follow this steps https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html

Comment: Thanks guys that helped resolve rest framework import but I am still having issue with my main problem. Site still complaining no module named

Comment: try: 'from serializers import SupplierPartViewSet' in your url.py

Comment: Your serializer source file is really called serializes.py? the convention its use "serializers.py".